# Angular 2: Dynamically bind dependent expression to a variable in a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, two-way-binding

I'm trying to bind an expression to a dynamically created field in a Angular dynamic form. I am using the cookbook code given in Angular site as reference, but not able to quite achieve what I'm looking for. I want 'c' to bind the dynamically created 'a' and 'b' form controls. 
My application's aim is to get scientific equations from the user and execute the equations as you change the input values. Please help.

```
  new TextboxQuestion({
    key: 'a',
    label: 'Breadth',
    value: 2,
    required: true,
    order: 4
  }),

  new TextboxQuestion({
    key: 'b',
    label: 'Length',
    value: 2,
    required: true,
    order:5
  }),
  new LabelQuestion({
    key: 'c',
    formula:'a*b',
    order: 6,
    type:'text'
  }),
```

I am trying to do an 'eval' of the formula to convert it to an expression after the form fields are set up. How can I ensure two way binding after I create the form group?

My LabelQuestion component is as below

```
import { QuestionBase } from './question-base';

export class LabelQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {
  controlType = 'label';
  type: string;
  options: {key: string, value: string}[] = [];


  constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super(options);
    this.type = options['type'] || '';
  }

}
```

And the dynamic-component.html is as follows.

```
   <div [formGroup]="form">
    <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>

    <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">

    <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="question.key"
            [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type" [(ngModel)]="question.key">

    <select [id]="question.key" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [formControlName]="question.key">
      <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
    </select>
    <input [id]="question.key" *ngSwitchCase="'label'" [formControlName]="question.key" [type]="question.type"
    >
  </div>

  <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} is required</div>
</div>
```